# $scope inside a callback of a resource get call will not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

i am having a problem accessing the $scope. as it seems it is not working for me.

i have a resource:

```
squashApp.factory('CourtsService', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/court/:num', {num: '@num'});
});
```

and my controller does:

```
squashApp.controller('CourtsController',
    function CourtsController($scope, $window, $http, CourtsService) {        
        CourtsService.get({num:1}, function(data){
                     $scope.courts = data;
        })

  });
```

my server succeeds in returing a data which is in format of javascript object (JSON).
i have checked it. but for some reason the $scope is not updated and after this callback my view is not changing at all.

help please

Comment: Try doing $scope.$apply(); after $scope.courts = data;

Comment: tried it, still won't work. i added $apply to my dependency list just to make sure this still isn't working...

Comment: `$apply` is not an Angular service; it's just a method of `$rootScope`.

Comment: How about this: $scope.courts = CourtsService.get({num:1});

Comment: put a `console.log` before the assignment, can you see `data` returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a demo for you and your code looks ok.

However, it is always good to add some logic for the callback when the error occurs like this, so your app will not die silently.

```
squashApp.controller('CourtsController', function CourtsController($scope, $window, $http, CourtsService) {
    CourtsService.get({
        num: 1
    }, function (data) {
        console.log('success');
        $scope.courts = data;
    }, function (data) { // -> error handling
        console.log('failed');
        $scope.courts = data;
    })
});
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dr6FM/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: i receive that data and it is correct, but still my UI will not update. should i do something to data before assigning it to scope.courts? as it seems that some how the data that the scope receives cannot be interrputed correctly

Comment: maybee it has to do to the way my server sends the data?
res.send(200, result);
is this the problem?
i just don't know what to do to make scope accept it correctly

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to access your $scope using angular $resource by using $promise (recommended)

```
  squashApp.controller('CourtsController',
    function CourtsController($scope,CourtsService) {        
        CourtsService.get({num:1}).$promise.then(function(data){
          //$scope -- can be accessed here
       }, function(failed){
       }
  });
```